# Transistor current control with positive feedback differential amplifier

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, control-system

[image: opAmp]

Hi Folks,

I want to analyse the functionality of following OpAmp configuration which seems to be employed as voltage - current conversion. Positive feedback (This is not a Failure and is intentionally done so !) from current sense resistor 1 Ohm is being fed back to Op Amp and compared with reference voltage +15V while being added to \$V_{in}\$. The error signal is amplified by open loop gain of OpAmp to drive the transistor emitter current. The transistor emitter current is almost equal to transistor collector current.

I would appreciate if someone can add further to my analysis.

$$V_{out} = A \cdot (V_+ - V_-)$$

$$Ie = \dfrac{V_{out} - V_{be}}{R_e}$$

\$I_c\$ is approximately equal to \$I_e\$, voltage at feedback node is:

$$V_c = 15 - I_c$$

\$V_+\$ is again depending on output current \$I_c\$, which can be solved using simultaneous equations.

The problem is, when this circuit is simulated in LtSpice the gain of OpAmp which is mentioned to be 85dB in data sheet as typical value doesn't comply exactly with the output voltage from simulation but only for a small range of input voltages. For different range of input values \$V_{in}\$, only certain values of calculated output voltages \$V_{out}\$ come out to be same as from simulation and few even exceed \$+V_{cc}\$ which is not possible in simulation as it saturates at \$+V_{cc}\$.

It looks as if either the gain of OpAmp varies with different input voltages or my mathematical modelling has errors.

I would like to share your experience generally about the configuration, and any hints about mathematical transfer function from \$V_{in}\$ to output emitter current of NPN transistor.

Comment: This isn't positive feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit is negative feedback due to the inversion provided by the common emitter transistor amplifier.

The collector voltage is: \$V_c=15-I_c\$.

Now, the op amp summing junction must be at 15 V, therefore the relationship for the voltage divider formed by \$R_2\$ and \$R_f\$ is:

$$\frac{V_c-15}{R_f}=\frac{15-V_{in}}{R_2}$$

Substituting  \$V_c=15-I_c\$ gives:
$$I_c=\frac{R_f}{R_2}(V_{in}-15) $$

Which is a voltage controlled current source.

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake in circuit. Instead of +15V at inverting input of OpAmp, we have +6V. Isn't OpAmp in this appöication being used as Open Lopp Amplifier ? becuase I see in Siumlation that the output voltage of OpAmp triggers from -Vcc to +Vcc as the sum of feedback current and Vin voltage is greater than 6V. In this case, you mean V+, the non inverting input of op amp has to be at 6V to drive the circuit ? Ic = Rf / R2 (Vin - 6V)??? in LtSpice Simulation, it doesn't seem to hold. Could you please explain your analysis ?

Comment: So, replace 15 V with 6 V in the voltage divider equation. And no, it's not open loop, it's negative feedback - if \$I_c\$ increases due to a load change, \$V_c\$ decreases; the summing junction voltage decreases; the base voltage of the BJT decreases; the base current of the BJT decreases; and thus \$I_c\$ decreases, thereby correcting the increase due to load change.

Comment: Thanks alot Chu. Yes it's working. if I replace V+ to be 6V and apply voltage divider as you did, the collector current comes to be Ic = 9 - (6 - Vin) Rf / R2 ; But the problem is I get Ic to be linear only from 0V < Vin < 0.58V. Beyond this point the output current Ic saturates and so is Vc. 1) Do you have an idea why do I face this limitation? 2) How Re is effecting this output current Ic ?

Comment: The current must limit somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

What if your transistor has lumped Re=2ohm, Rc = 5ohm, Rb=1Kohm in the model?
That transistor has 1Ohm external, 5ohm in collector, 2ohm in emitter, totally 8 ohms. Max current is < 2 amps. And maximum voltage across the 1Ohm sense resistor is < 2 volts. Approx 13 volts is the lowest Vcollector can be.

Answer (score 0):

> Transistor current control with positive feedback differential
>   amplifier

No, it's not positive feedback - it's still negative feedback because the BJT provides a signal inversion. So, on the face of it, the BJT is driven by the op-amp to produce a collector voltage that satisfies the standard negative feedback equations associated with a more conventionally connected op-amp.

With Vin at 15 volts, the collector voltage will be exactly 15 volts but this is problematic because the supply (via the collector resistor) is only 15 volt therefore the BJT will be turned off.

With Vin below 15 volt the BJT remains cut-off.

With Vin above 15 volts (and let's say Rf and R2 are equal value), Vc will drop below 15 volts by the same amount Vin is above 15 volts.

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake in circuit. Instead of +15V at inverting input of OpAmp, we have +6V. Isn't OpAmp in this appöication being used as Open Lopp Amplifier ? becuase I see in Siumlation that the output voltage of OpAmp triggers from -Vcc to +Vcc as the sum of feedback current and Vin voltage is greater than 6V. I am beginner in linear electronics :) Do you mean the collector voltage should be equal to Vc = -Rf/R2 (Vin - 6V) ??

Comment: Yes that is what it should equal.

Comment: this relation is not being satisfied in simulation if I use Re = 1 Ohm and Vin = 0.3V. the answer should be 8.55 V but i get instead 14.5494 V

Comment: I don't know what values you have for Rf and R2. I also don't know what transistor you have or whether it can handle the currents implied by 15-8.55V/1ohm (6.45 amps) and I doubt the the hFE of the transistor is going to be much more than 20 with this current so asking the op-amp to supply over 300 mA to the base is not going to happen. Use more realistic value resistors to see if it works.

Comment: Transistor is NPN Q2N2222 (Ic, max = 0.8 A), OpAmp is LM7171. Rf = R2. If I need 14.5V at collector that means 0.5A output current, according to this relation I must provide Vin = -8.5V. but this doesn't work in LtSpice simulation. For Ic > 500mA, hFE is > 40 in datasheet of transistor