# Transistor based Voltage-Current Converter

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, control, converter, feedback

For my last design question, [Transistor current control with collector feedback](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299110/transistor-current-control-with-collector-feedback/299118#299118), I want to add a NPN transistor between OpAmp and already shown transistor in common emitter mode. With new design, the base of output transistor (already included) will be driven by newly added NPN transistor as collector load.

My question is:
To design the values of RE and RC of newly added transistor, which factors do I need to consider ?

What I already know is only that the total resistance of new Transistor should be adjusted such that it's base current Ib does not exceed the output current limit of OpAmp----- Ic = 15 / R and Ib = Ic / hFE

Now how do I adjust this calculated current limiting resistance R between Collector and Emitter of a new transistor. As far as I know, Emitter Resistance is also feedback to input voltage.

The circuit operates in linear mode.

Thanks in Anticipation for your time and opinion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHQ1Ow.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A schematic would really help here......

Comment: I'll go Trevor one better - without a schematic, there is no way to answer your question, since there is no way to be certain what circuit you are proposing, and no way to determine what your resistors actually do. I can guess, but I don't know. So edit your post and use the schematic icon (the one with the diode), or hit ctrl-m.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast

Comment: The new transistor inverts the signal.  What does that do to your feedback?

Comment: That circuit will not regulate current. It will regulate voltage at one end of the sense/load resistor. Any change in supply voltage (including ripple and noise) will be reflected directly in the current. Also, in your linked circuit, you have missed the fact that the load is normally connected to the collector of the NPN. As owg60 comments, your feedback polarity is wrong.  Finally, the base of Q2 will force the Q1 collector to a range of 0 to 0.7 volts or so, so it won't work the way you think it will.

Comment: Change the gain on the feedback path, not on the output of the op amp, you also have positive feedback, not negative. Look up constant current source.

Comment: @laptop2d isn't it negative feedback? I have three inversion stages. OpAmp, Q1, Q2?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast exactly, I changed the shown topology in my last question "Transistor current control with collector feedback" because i need higher current at output which isn't managable for OpAmp alone as it can not provide more than 100mA at its output. So i want to insert multiple stages of Common Emitter transistor configurations in between to achieve enough gain to be able to obtain higher current (let's say 12 A) which can't be managed by a single transistor and OpAmp alone.

Comment: @owg60 the new transistor is to supposed to provide current gain to be able to achieve higher current at output. Yes it also inverts the signal.

Comment: @HerrderElektronik - What do you mean, "exactly"? I pointed out that you won't regulate current - do you want to or not? And anyways, your common emitter configuration won't work, since the next stage clamps the output to about 0.7 volts. Try looking up a Darlington configuration.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast becuase 1Ohm is a sense resistor, controlling voltage at (15 - I) node would in turn mean that I want to control my output current. I basically want to have a voltage-controlled current source of this art with OpAmp followed by Transistors. You are Right ! I have a failure in topology as you quote "And anyways, your common emitter configuration won't work, since the next stage clamps the output to about 0.7 volts." do you think a PNP transistor/ darlington would be a good choice in between Q1 and Q2 ? in that case my collector voltage of Q1 will not be clamped to 0.7V anymore.

Comment: @HerrderElektronik - Please. Just stop and reconsider your circuit. You are not controlling current. You are simply controlling the voltage at the bottom of the 1 ohm resistor. If you want to control current you must measure the voltage at both ends of the 1 ohm. Until you stop kidding yourself about this, there is no sense wasting time making suggestions about how to do it.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I appreciate your Interest ! Dont you think controlling voltage at one end of Resistor means controlling current ? in outer end transistor which measures to be I = 15 - Vc where Vc is collector voltage of BJT. Controlling Vc would imply that we are controlling output current.

Comment: @HerrderElektronik - " Dont you think controlling voltage at one end of Resistor means controlling current ?" Not unless you can guarantee stability of your +15. And, with unspecified current levels, unspecified power supplies and unspecified wire sizes there is no reason to think that you can make that claim.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast actually I am just learning this technique as a part of my bachelor thesis. My idea in this circuit diagram is just to bring in certain number of transistor levels so that I can have high current at the output like around 12A. If I would do this with only one OpAmp and BJT, OpAmp is unable to provide sufficient current to BJT to achieve it. So I put one more BJT in between which is not correct as marked by you because the collector voltage of first BJT is restricted by the next one. Brining in Darlington is a Nice idea from you. I would take PNP to avoid voltage problem

Comment: @HerrderElektronik - A PNP Darlington will only work if your op amp can produce nearly 15 volts, and very few will do that simply.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast and If I add a PNP darlinton not right after a OpAmp but between both transistors Q1 and Q2. Then?? This is where I am at the moment....  In that case do you know how to determine the value of RE?  It will be a feedback to output Pin voltage of OpAmp which I couldn't calculate

Comment: @HerrderElektronik - You misunderstand. The Darllington would replace Q1 and Q2.  And you still won't be able to drive it properly with most op amps. So forget your circuit. Use an NPN darlington to drive a grounded sense resistor. If you absolutely must have a grounded load (not the transistors), put the sense resistor between the load and the darlington emitter, and us a differential amplifier op amp circuit to sense the voltage across the sense resistor. Just forget your circuit idea. This is my last response - we've gone on too long.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Thanks alot dear. It was a great help meanwhile.